# Event driven serial port pyqt

Tags: python, serial-port

I'm looking for an answer for this question for a a few months, there is a c++ code design for QT to allow a serial port communication, one of it's features that allows to define an event driven serial read and wright, the code name is qextserialport and the code can be found  [here](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/)

I'm looking for an event driven code that will allow me to do the same in python and with QT, i searched for twisted serial communication documents and there isn't much out there.

Comment: Since you've been looking for a few months, it is perhaps time to just roll your own by using [`serial`](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/index.html), `QThreads` and QT's slots and signals.

Comment: Thanks i was fearing that, thank you